# Prime number finding via polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, functions, polynomials, prime-numbers

I try to find approximation polynomial to estimate which number is prime or not. Addtion to this, (If It is possible) To find the closed form of coefficients of the series ($c(n)$)

Euler found  [the formula](http://www.maa.org/editorial/euler/How%20Euler%20Did%20It%2050%20false%20log%20series.pdf) as shown below (Please see page 5)

$$\frac{1}{a-1}+\frac{1}{a^2-1}+\frac{1}{a^3-1}+....=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{a^k-1}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{2}{a^3}+\frac{3}{a^4}+\frac{2}{a^5}+\frac{4}{a^6}+....=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{c(k)}{a^k}$$

I checked wolframalpha for [this sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D++%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%5Ek-1%7D).

[image]

If we use $a=e^x$  then multiply by $e^{nx}$ both side.Then integrate both side.

$$c(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{2 \pi i} \frac{e^{nx}}{e^{kx}-1}dx$$

The formula satisfy the condition below.

For all $n>1$ integers

If $c(n)=2$ then $n$ is prime

If $c(n)>2$ then $n$ is not prime

$$c(n)\approx P(n) =a_0+a_1n+\frac{a_2n^2}{2!}+\frac{a_3n^3}{3!}+....+\frac{a_mn^m}{m!}=\sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{a_kn^k}{k!} $$

I wish to find coefficient of $P(n)$ for estimating prime numbers in quick way via a computer program. $m$ can be changed to get large prime numbers.

But I do not know how to use $$c(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{2 \pi i} \frac{e^{nx}}{e^{kx}-1}dx$$.

Is it possible to use some transforms on the formula and to get the required  result?

Maybe someone can give a hint how to start.

Thanks for helps

EDIT:

I have a starting idea to find approximation of $c(n)$. Maybe it can be helpful.

$$c(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{2 \pi i} \frac{e^{nx}}{e^{kx}-1}dx$$
$x=2 \pi i t$
$$c(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{1} \frac{e^{2 \pi i n t}}{e^{2 \pi i k t}-1}dt$$

$$c(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{1} \frac{\cos(2 \pi  n t)+i \sin(2 \pi  n t)}{\cos(2 \pi  k t)-1+i \sin(2 \pi  k t)}dt$$

$$c(n)=\frac{1}{2 }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{1} \frac{(\cos(2 \pi  n t)+i \sin(2 \pi  n t))(\cos(2 \pi  k t)-1-i \sin(2 \pi  k t))}{1-\cos(2 \pi  k t)}dt$$

$$c(n)=\frac{1}{2 }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{1} \frac{\cos(2 \pi  (n-k) t)-\cos(2 \pi  n t) }{1-\cos(2 \pi  k t)}dt+\frac{i}{2 }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{1} \frac{\sin(2 \pi  (n-k) t)-\sin(2 \pi  n t) }{1-\cos(2 \pi  k t)}dt$$

I am going to update if I get progress

Comment: What is $P(n)$? What are those coefficients $a_j$?

Comment: I don't see how you are going to approximate an arithmetic function with a Taylor polynomial.

Comment: @Ethan  I believe $c(n)$ must be infinite series but $P(n)$ is approximation of it.$a_m$ is constants.

Comment: $c(n)$ is the divisor function $c(n)=d(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} 1$, it counts how many divisors $n$ has.

Comment: @Ethan I see. Do you know how we can find a polynomial that has near results of $d(n)$?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A polynomial would not be a good approximation of $d(n)$, because $d(n)$ behaves very erratically, we have $d(n)=2$ infinitely often, and likewise $d(n)$ can be made as large as we want. Though in terms of series expansions for arithmetic functions, the only thing I know of are "Ramanujan sums" these are very nice looking, but I am not sure how good they are for computation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_sum.

Comment: @Ethan thanks for help. I actually I wish to find such polinomials http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html  for $c(n)$ but as you said there are a lot of $2$ results would be and very hard to find such polynomials.Now I think that It is also can be OK to find some elementary functions approximations of $c(n)$ .

Comment: @Mathlover the basic sticking point is that elementary functions behave very nicely in general while $c(n)$ behaves very erratically.  There are, however, approximations of the *average* of $c(n)$, i.e. $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} c(n) = \log n + O(1).$$